# Application menu dropdowns right-aligned in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I've noticed in two of my Windows 7 installs (both 64-bit) that after the last couple of updates, most application menus seem to be right-aligned instead of left as if there's not enough room to display it left-aligned (the window is 1600px wide, so plenty of room there).

Any thoughts as to how to switch this back to the default? Pretty much every application is affected – Adobe CS4, VS2010, Notepad.

Comment: I was afflicted by this on Windows 10 too, and the solution in the answer fixed it too!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Press the Windows logo key+R to bring up the Run dialog box. In the Open line, copy/paste the following line of text.

   ```
   shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}
   ```
2. Press OK.

   This will start the Tablet PC Settings configuration dialog (Even if you do not have a Tablet PC).
3. Select the Other Tab.
4. In the Handedness section, place a check mark in the Left Handed option.
5. Click OK.

Remember to restart Explorer after doing this.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it. Had no idea it had to do with tablet settings.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! I've lived with this "feature" for months and only just got around to finding how to fix it. It has been bugging me for sooooo long.

Comment: If you're scared about that shell command, just hit the windows key, type "Tablet" and pick the Tablet PC Settings.

Comment: Works for Windows 10 too. I always wondered why it happened? Is it because my laptop, though certainly not a tablet, has a touch screen?

Comment: This happened to me on my desktop - so I'm even _more_ confused how this got enabled. Anyway, thanks for the simple fix!